# how do i put the supplier names on my sql table to an array so that i may use it for a combo box?

Tags: java, arrays, jdbc

what im trying to do is to declare:

```
String[] supplierOnList;
```

then later on do this?

```
Global.rs = Global.s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM medSupplier");
int cou = 0;
while(Global.rs.next())
{
    Global.supplierOnList[cou]=Global.rs.getString("sName");
    System.out.println(Global.supplierOnList[cou]);
    cou++;
}
```

is there a better way for me to this? what i want to do is to use the array for drop down list.

```
    String[] petStrings = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig" };

    //Create the combo box, select the item at index 4.
    //Indices start at 0, so 4 specifies the pig.
    JComboBox petList = new JComboBox(petStrings);
    petList.setSelectedIndex(4);
    petList.addActionListener(this);


    }

    /** Listens to the combo box. */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String petName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        updateLabel(petName);
     }
```

Comment: Use a `List<String>`?

Comment: Please delete `Global`. **Pretty please**. It's for your own good. In fact, it's so *heinous* I refused to see it at first.

Comment: Your question became so wired. :(

Comment: @SanjayaPandey yeah i know. i just want to put the supplier names from an sql table to an array and then use that array for a combox box drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<dataType>`.

```
    Like List<String> supplierOnList = new ArrayList<>();

    Global.rs = Global.s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM medSupplier");

    while(Global.rs.next()){
        Global.supplierOnList.add(Global.rs.getString("sName"));
        // OR supplierOnList.add(Global.rs.getString("sName"));
    }
```

To print `List` data :

```
for(int i =0 ;i<supplierOnList.size();i++){
   System.out.println("List Data :: " + supplierOnList.get(i));
}
```

Add items into `JCombobox` :

```
for(int i =0 ;i<supplierOnList.size();i++){
       petList.addItem(new ComboItem(supplierOnList.get(i)), supplierOnList.get(i))));
}
```

onclick of `jCombobox` :

```
        supplierOnList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JComboBox jcmbDates = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
                // do your stuff here
            }
        })
```

;

Comment: how do i put in a combo box?

Comment: @javaMan - Post Your combobox code which you have tried.

Comment: String[] petStrings = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig" };
    JComboBox petList = new JComboBox(petStrings);
    petList.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    String petName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
    updateLabel(petName);
    }

here is the code that im trying to edit.

Comment: hello man, can't you post this code in your question by editing it, it's looking so weird.

Comment: @javaMan Please tell me you're a vet. Or explain in what way are `medSupplier` and `petStrings` are synonyms. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no man, that's a sample code i found over the internet on how to create combo box from arrays. i just want to be able to put the supplier names in the array so i can use it for a combo box drop down menu. if there's an easier way let me know. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using list of string:

```
List<String> supplierOnList = new ArrayList<String>();

Global.rs = Global.s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM medSupplier");
int cou = 0;
while(Global.rs.next())
{
    Global.supplierOnList[cou]=Global.rs.getString("sName");
    supplierOnList.add(Global.supplierOnList[cou]);
    cou++;
}
//output line
System.out.println("The output list of supplierOnList  is:"+supplierOnList);
```

Use this array list:

```
for(String supplier : supplierOnList){
  //you will get individual supplier
  System.out.println("Supplier is:"+supplier);
}
```

Comment: Global.supplierOnList = new ArrayList<>();
                      
while(Global.rs.next())
                      
{
                      
Global.supplierOnList.add(Global.rs.getString("sName"));
                       cou++;
                      }
                      
                  Global.supplierList = new JComboBox(Global.supplierOnList);
            Global.supplierList.setSelectedIndex(cou);

said it should be parameterized.

Comment: Sorry,I can't correctly understand what you are saying.Please make it more clear.Say, what is your requirement?

Comment: @javaMan Declare `supplierOnList` like this `List<String> supplierOnList` you must be using `List supplierOnList`.

Answer (score 0):

If I have followed you, then what you really want is a generic "Combo Box Builder" that can take a `Collection`, a `selectedIndex` and an `ActionListener`; that is something like

```
private static <T> JComboBox<T> buildComboBox(Collection<T> options, int selectedIndex, 
      ActionListener al)
{
  JComboBox<T> jcb = new JComboBox<T>();
  for (T item : options) {
    jcb.addItem(item);
  }
  if (selectedIndex < 0) {
    selectedIndex = 0;
  } else if (selectedIndex >= options.size()) {
    selectedIndex = options.size() - 1;
  }
  jcb.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
  if (al != null) {
    jcb.addActionListener(al);
  }
  return jcb;
}
```

Comment: yeah something like that! can i copy this code as it is?

Comment: @javaMan Yes, but [Attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).